# Apply SSL for tomcat 10 with the jdk 17.0.6

Tags: ssl, war, java-11, java-17, tomcat10

When I tried to apply SSL for tomcat 10 with the open jdk 17, the SSL is not getting applied whereas i did the same for tomcat 9 with open jdk 11, it works. I followed the same step.

Open command prompt from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\bin\ and enter the below commands

1. keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
2. keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file myFQDN.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore

Take the CSR and apply it in Godaddy download the tomcat file then followed below steps

3. keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\bin\gd_bundle.crt"
4. keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\bin\myFQDN.crt"

I followed these four steps and added the connectors in tomcat server.xml

<  Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150"  minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"  enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"  acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="somename"  keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\xyz.jks"  keystorePass="password" />

I tried both JKS and Keystore file.....Do anyone have any idea?

Need to apply SSL for tomcat 10 with open jdk 17

Comment: Same thing for me. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying openssl with pkcs12 format and it worked.